# EmptyCell: DeferRefresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a (.NET Framework 4.6.1) wpf-window with a datagrid bound to a collection on my mainwindow. This collection contains a property of type decimal.

[image]

When I clear the cell it gets a red border.

[image]

Here is the window-constructor

```
public WdwSapAccounting()
{
    DataContext = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;
    var x = MainWindow.Reference.CurrentAction.ACCOUNTING_COLLECTION;
    InitialiseComponent();
}
```

Now I close the window (cell is empty). I reopen the window and debug my `variable x`. It says the sum is still 200. On next command `InitialiseComponent();` it crashes with the error:

> **DeferRefresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction**

I tried FallBackValue and TargetNullValue but both don't catch the empty cell and don't catch this weird exception. I tried CommitEdit() and CancelEdit() but this also doesn't help:

```
        private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridAccounting.CommitEdit();
        dataGridAccounting.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void MetroWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridAccounting.CommitEdit();
        dataGridAccounting.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void dataGridAccounting_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridAccounting.CommitEdit();
        dataGridAccounting.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void dataGridAccounting_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridAccounting.CommitEdit();
        dataGridAccounting.CancelEdit();
    }
```

Here is the xml of my datagrid.

```
 <DataGrid MinHeight="150" Loaded="dataGridAccounting_Loaded" UnloadingRow="dataGridAccounting_UnloadingRow" UnloadingRowDetails="dataGridAccounting_UnloadingRowDetails"
                LoadingRow="DataGridAccounting_LoadingRow" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
                x:Name="dataGridAccounting" CellEditEnding="dataGridAccounting_CellEditEnding"
                CurrentCellChanged="DataGridAccounting_CurrentCellChanged" Unloaded="dataGridAccounting_Unloaded"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentAction.ACCOUNTING_COLLECTION, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BETRAG, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N, FallbackValue=0.0, TargetNullValue=0.0}" Header="BETRAG"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `decimal` property cannot be set to something like `null` or an empty string.

You can use a converter to tell WPF to set it back to `0.0` (`default(decimal)`) when you clear the cell:

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string StringFormat { get; set; } = "N";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        value;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        decimal.TryParse(value?.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, culture, out decimal d) ? d : default;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:DecimalConverter x:Key="DecimalConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding BETRAG, StringFormat=N, FallbackValue=0.0, TargetNullValue=0.0,
                        Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"
                    Header="BETRAG"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or change the type of `BETRAG` to `Nullable<decimal>` (`decimal?`).

Comment: I don't want to change the datatype to nullable. The solution with converter looks really great, thank you very much! I will try this soon!

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and sorry for not accepting it meanwhile. Thank you very much for your help!